# Git diff is complaining, "external diff died, stopping at ... " with my python diff program

Tags: python, git, subprocess, return-value, git-diff

Here's the beginning part of my diff.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import fileinput
import difflib
import subprocess
import sys

# for debugging
def info(type, value, info):
    import traceback
    traceback.print_exception(type, value, info)
    print
    pdb.pm()

sys.excepthook = info
import pdb
#end debugging

if len(sys.argv) == 8:
    # assume this was passed to git; we can of course do
    # some parsing to check if we got valid git style args
    args = [sys.argv[2], sys.argv[5]]
elif len(sys.argv) == 3:
    args = sys.argv[1:]
else:
    exit("Not a valid number of args (2 or 7) to this diff program")
print "Files: " + ' '.join(args)
for filename in args:
    filetype = subprocess.check_output(['file', filename])
    if filetype.find('text') == -1:
        args.insert(0, 'diff')
        print "A binary file was found: " + filename + ", deferring to diff"
        exit(subprocess.call(args))
```

When a binary (or otherwise non text) file is encountered, it attempts to fork `diff` to obtain whether the binary files differ or not. The goal is for this python diff program to be used as an external differ for git.

But I get this ghastly "external diff died, stopping at <file>" message once it hits the binary file.

How is git evaluating my program? How does it know it died? Isn't return value supposed to indicate the differing condition?

Comment: I may give up on "external diff" configuration and set my python diff up as one of the "difftools". Hopefully that will work better.

Comment: It works, but I really want to be able to use my diff for e.g. `git log -p`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no exit function in your code. How about replace `exit` to `sys.exit`?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess
import sys

if len(sys.argv) == 8:
    # assume this was passed to git; we can of course do
    # some parsing to check if we got valid git style args
    args = [sys.argv[2], sys.argv[5]]
elif len(sys.argv) == 3:
    args = sys.argv[1:]
else:
    print "Not a valid number of args (2 or 7) to this diff program"
    sys.exit(1)
print "Files: ", args
for filename in args:
    filetype = subprocess.check_output(['file', filename])
    if filetype.find('text') == -1:
        args.insert(0, 'diff')
        print "A binary file was found: " + filename + ", deferring to diff"
        #sys.stdout.flush()
        subprocess.call(args)
        sys.exit(0)
```

EDIT: [`git` depend on external diff's exit status.](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f678d9b5923b030287687dde020240c2d4709d79/diff.c#L2925) `diff` exit with 0 only if there is no differce. So changed the code not to use diff's exit status.

PS: Without sys.stdout.flush(), `diff` output come before `print` output.

Comment: `exit` (which quits the program) and `sys.exit` (which also quits the program)

Comment: They are same. But you used the exit which is not imported. (`from sys import exit')

Comment: Well. either way it does the same thing. I'm gonna have to look up `git` source code it seems.

Comment: You should have `from sys import exit` statement if you don't want to replace exit with sys.exit.

Comment: Well which one should I use? Why are there two?

Comment: Ya. same problem. You only changed the `exit()` bit, yes?

Comment: Thanks for digging up source at github. Looks like it assumes the retval of the external program indicates error instead of "different". I guess the "external diff" interface is less friendly than the difftool interface